# When and how should I choose universities which will get my exam scores?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gre, toefl

I'm going to apply for a graduate programs (PhD) that require TOEFL, GRE General and GRE Subject tests. Since deadlines for most programs in USA or Europe are somewhere in December-January and two available test dates for Subject test in my location are September and October, I thought that I will be able to choose schools where I will apply after passing exams. But a couple of days ago I realised that it is necessary to match 4 target schools as a part of registration process for TOEFL or GRE.

My questions are:

- Will I be able to change universities after registration for TOEFL and GRE? Are there any deadlines?
- How and when can I match additional universities if I want to apply more than four places?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question can best be answered by ETS, the source of both exams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to choose 4 universities at the test. Don't worry, you can still choose other universities to get your score with fees (universities other than the chosen 4). You can choose the additional universities from your account on GRE or TEOFL websites (after the test). The score will arrive at the additional university  after 4 weeks of choosing them on website (maybe 6 weeks I am not sure).

You can ask about the details of the fees on gre or TOEFL page on facebook. they are very helpful.

Best of luck